# (beginner Q) type error in a lambda

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, typeerror

I am getting the following error:

---

cube_list=lambda i,x=0 : list(map(x**3, range(0,i)))

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

---

Goal of this line was to produce a list of cubed numbers by giving the last number that is supposed to be cubed as i.
x is set to 0, but can be changed to swap the starting number.

This is probably pretty easy to fix but I just don't see it as I am just starting to learn programming
Thank you very much in advance! and happy coding everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `map` must be a function.

```
>>> cube_list = lambda n: list(map(lambda x: x**3, range(n)))
>>> cube_list(3)
[0, 1, 8]
```

You can write this more simply.

```
>>> cube_list_2 = lambda n: [_**3 for _ in range(n)]
>>> cube_list_2(3)
[0, 1, 8]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the fast answer! 
so, the problem was that x\**3 is in fact not a function but an operation which leads to the failing _map_ function

i modified your code again to fit my desire to change the starting point as originally intended:

cube_list_2 = lambda n,m=0: [x\**3 for x in range(m,n+1)]